# Find specific character with python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings looking like this:

```
H PL->01 Tx=000/006 Ph=00/000  DGDD DDDR YDyD GRDD YGR  Dets=     003,003,003,003,003,003,003,003,003,003,003,003,  ports= 255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,'
```

I want to be able to extract the content tha matches `DGDD DDDR YDyD GRDD YGR`(this changes but always has the letters `D,G,R,Y,y` and its length may change) and put it in a list without whitespaces like this:

```
 ['D', 'G', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'R', 'Y', 'D', 'y', 'D', 'G', 'R', 'D', 'D', 'Y', 'G', 'R']
```

Comment: Is it always at the same place in the line?

Comment: And you want to find sequences only consist of the characters 'D', 'G', 'R', 'Y', 'y' and whitespace and then remove whitespace?

Comment: @JonClements It always starts in the same place but doesnt end in the same place.It could be 16 character or 17 or 15.

Comment: @freakazoid_em Yes i want find sequences that consist of the characters 'D', 'G', 'R', 'Y', 'y'  not including the character 'D' from Dets and any other character after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the criteria is groups of `DGRYy` that have at least three characters, then you can use a regex to that effect and then "flatten" it to a list after... eg:

```
import re
from itertools import chain
print list(chain.from_iterable(re.findall('[DGRYy]{3,}', data)))
# ['D', 'G', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'R', 'Y', 'D', 'y', 'D', 'G', 'R', 'D', 'D', 'Y', 'G', 'R']
```

If it's always between two items, then it's possible to use the builtin string functions to extract it, eg:

```
print [ch for ch in data[data.index('Ph'):].partition('Dets=')[0].split(' ', 1)[1] if ch != ' ']
```

Comment: the last 3 YGR could be either 1 or 2 characters.If i use print list(chain.from_iterable(re.findall('[DGRYy]{3,}', data))) with 1 instead of 3 it extracts the "D" from the word "Dets". Is there a way to not extract the D from Dets?

Comment: @vkefallinos is it always a group of five?

Comment: no its not always a group of five.There could be three groups of four characters and one group of 3 or 2 or 1.Its always between  Ph=**** and Dets

Comment: Jon, did you accidentally edit the OP's question instead of this answer?

Comment: @DSM - oh... my.... god.... - yes, I rolled it back, TY (that isn't embarrassing at all ;()

Comment: Heh.  Well, I spent three St Patrick's days in England myself.  Even by diffusion it'll leave you making silly mistakes. :^)

Comment: @DSM I'd completely forgotten it was St Patricks day as well - always a good excuse to buy Guinness ;)